# Struggling with codecamp: Record Collection (JSON)

Tags: json

I know a lot of people have asked this, but none of the solutions have worked for me so far. The instructions are:
If prop isn't "tracks" and value isn't empty (""), update or set the value for that record album's property.

Your function must always return the entire collection object.

There are several rules for handling incomplete data:

If prop is "tracks" but the album doesn't have a "tracks" property, create an empty array before adding the new value to the album's corresponding property. (I think this is my problem, but can't figure out how to include it)

If prop is "tracks" and value isn't empty (""), push the value onto the end of the album's existing tracks array.

My current attempt is:

```
 function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
 if(prop == "tracks" && value !== ""){
collection[id][prop].push(value);
} else 
 if (value !==""){
  collection[id][prop] = value;
   } else 
if (value === ""){
     delete collection[id][prop];
   } 
 return collection;
}
```

(Sorry about the formatting, i'm just learning to use this page)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for over two hours, I guess. Found the solution, but can't understand how it works. Hope it helps.

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
if (prop !== "tracks" && value !== "") {
collection[id][prop] = value;
} else if (prop == "tracks" && collection[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks") === false)  {
collection[id][prop] = [];
collection[id][prop].push(value);
} else if (prop == "tracks" && value !== "") {
collection[id].tracks.push(value);
} else if (value === "") {
delete collection[id][prop];
}


return collection;
}
```